# Show that 5 is a primitive root for any Fermat prime other than itself.

Tags: number-theory

I dont know how to prove this result. Any help is appreciated. I prefer an answer without complex algebra, thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268125/elementary-proof-that-3-is-a-primitive-root-of-a-fermat-prime

Comment: There's at least one Fermat prime for which the statement isn't true, so that one, at least, needs to be excluded.

Comment: @ionza I edited the, uh, mysterious exceptional case.  Somewhat oddly the claim works also for $3$ but not for $17$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use the law of quadratic reciprocity to show that $5$ is not a quadratic residue modulo the Fermat prime.

Comment: Yeah, i guess that showing 5 is not a quadratic residue mod Fermat prime, then 5 is a primitive root, since **all primitive roots of a fermat prime are non quadratic residue**, and the sets are the same since they have the same  number of elements.