# Establish that 7 is a primitive root of any prime of the form $p = 2^{4n} + 1$.

Tags: number-theory

Establish that 7 is a primitive root of any prime of the form $p = 2^{4n} + 1$.

[Hint: Because $p ≡ 3$ or $5 \ (mod \ 7)$, $(7/p) = (p/7)=-1$].

I get that $p ≡ 2, 3, 5 \ (mod \ 7)$. Not only 3,5. How should i think?

Answer (score 7):

We're interested in the group $(\Bbb Z / p \Bbb Z)^\times$. This group is cyclic of size $2^{4n}$, so it has $\varphi(2^{4n}) = 2^{4n-1} = \frac{1}{2} 2^{4n}$ generators. That is, half of its elements are generators, and since quadratic residues cannot be generators, we see that the generators are precisely the quadratic nonresidues, which includes $7$.

Comment: I havet studied group theory, som it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I didn't see this before, but here is a more elementary explanation.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395652/for-every-prime-of-the-form-24n1-7-is-a-primitive-root?rq=1

Comment: I'd like too se a prove with the given hint!

Comment: grape answer needs an upvote

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$2^{4n}+1=16^n+1=2^n+1\pmod 7=\begin{cases}3\\5\end{cases}\pmod 7$$

Note that

$$2^{3}+1=(2+1)(2^2-2+1)\;\;\text{can't be prime}$$

and this is why $\;2\pmod 7\;$ isn't included in the hints...